# Child records fields editable if parent is read only for profile

Tags: sharing, master-detail, parent

I have one object - A ( Custom Object) is the master  to object B ( Child Object).  A is set to read only for P (profile).

A is from managed package which was installed by one vendor. Is there any way we can open child object's fields to become editable for Profile P ( Since we don't have source code control of Managed Package.)

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0):

As A and B has Master detail relationship so A control all permission/ sharing setting for B.

For this you don't need source control instead you can create a permission set of all additional permission (Create, Update) related to A and then assign it to P Profile. So your user get all required permission.

Comment: Thanks Tushar, i tried with permission set. But unfornately it didn't work. Any other solution you would suggest?